# View serializable schedule

Tags: serialization

> Any view serializable schedule that is not conflict serializable must contain a blind write.

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_write))

Why is this statement true? I referred some links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941901/view-serializable-and-conflict-serializable) but am still not able to visualize the correctness of the above statement.